# how to correct this code to verify for all the a's in the code to check for the sample code?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

The following program calculates the number of input strings with letter ‘a’, and end the program when the input string is “####”. Here is an expected sample run:

enter a string (enter #### to stop): apple
enter a string (enter #### to stop): banana
enter a string (enter #### to stop): strawberry
enter a string (enter #### to stop): book
enter a string (enter #### to stop): ####
3 strings with letter 'a'

```
count=0
while str!= "####":
    str = input("enter a string: ")
    for letter in str:
        if letter in str = 'a':
            count +=1
        else:
            break
print(count , "strings with letter 'a'")
```

Comment: What is this? if letter in str = 'a':

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name, change it to `string` or `s` or `word` or `umbrella`, pretty much anything but `str`

Comment: Especially `if letter in str = 'a':` is wrong in many ways. You just want to check if the letter is equal to "a", that is `if letter == "a":`. You also don't want to break the loop if it isn't "a".

Comment: This `if letter in str = 'a':` doesn't work, but `if 'a' in str:` does (without the `for` loop even) - except that you shouldn't use `str` as a name for a variable, since it is shadowing the name of the `str` type. Just rename `str` to `s` or whatever.

Comment: @Michael Butscher.. NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some problems:

- it shadows the name of the type `str` with your variable named `str`
- it checks every letter and could increase `count` for the number of 'a's, but you want to count words
- `letter in str = 'a'` is not a valid condition

Fixing all that:

```
count = 0
s = ''
while s != "####":
    s = input("enter a string: ")
    if 'a' in s:
        count += 1
print(count , "strings with letter 'a'")
```

Comment: There is no point in both of us offering the same solution.

Comment: @Alexander your solution offered no explanation, and contained an error, using `text.count('a')`, so I provided an alternative.